# Save Button Activation c#/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I make sure that as soon as there is a change in the text field, the save button is enabled? or clicking edit (thus creating the button) the app enables editing and thus enabling the button, 
and it has already been activated in case of insertion or deletion.

this a image of 
[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTMXD.png)

Here is the code:

```
public GerenciarGenericoViewModel()
        {
            InserirProdutoCommand = new RelayCommand(InserirProduto);
            ExcluirProdutoCommand = new RelayCommand(ExcluirProduto, CanExcluirProduto);

            InserirUnidadeCommand = new RelayCommand(InserirUnidade);
            ExcluirUnidadeCommand = new RelayCommand(ExcluirUnidade, CanExcluirUnidade);

            InserirEmpresaCommand = new RelayCommand(InserirEmpresa);
            ExcluirEmpresaCommand = new RelayCommand(ExcluirEmpresa, CanExcluirEmpresa);

            InserirOperadorCommand = new RelayCommand(InserirOperador);
            ExcluirOperadorCommand = new RelayCommand(ExcluirOperador, CanExcluirOperador);

            SalvarCommand = new RelayCommand(Salvar, CanSalvar);
            CancelarCommand = new RelayCommand(Cancelar);

            ListaProdutos = new ObservableCollection<Produto>(ProdutosAccess.GetProdutos());
            ListaUnidades = new ObservableCollection<UnidadeMedida>(ProdutosAccess.GetUnidadesMedida());
            ListaEmpresas = new ObservableCollection<Empresa>(ProdutosAccess.GetEmpresas());
            ListaOperadores = new ObservableCollection<Operador>(ProdutosAccess.GetOperadores());

        }

        public RelayCommand InserirProdutoCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand ExcluirProdutoCommand { get; }

        public RelayCommand InserirUnidadeCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand ExcluirUnidadeCommand { get; }

        public RelayCommand InserirEmpresaCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand ExcluirEmpresaCommand { get; }

        public RelayCommand InserirOperadorCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand ExcluirOperadorCommand { get; }

        int check = 0;

        public RelayCommand SalvarCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand CancelarCommand { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<Produto> ListaProdutos { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<UnidadeMedida> ListaUnidades { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Empresa> ListaEmpresas { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Operador> ListaOperadores { get; }

        private Produto _produtoSelecionado;
        public Produto ProdutoSelecionado
        {
            get => _produtoSelecionado;
            set => Set(() => ProdutoSelecionado, ref _produtoSelecionado, value);
        }

        private UnidadeMedida _unidadeSelecionada;
        public UnidadeMedida UnidadeSelecionada
        {
            get => _unidadeSelecionada;
            set => Set(() => UnidadeSelecionada, ref _unidadeSelecionada, value);
        }

        private Empresa _empresaSelecionada;
        public Empresa EmpresaSelecionada
        {
            get => _empresaSelecionada;
            set => Set(() => EmpresaSelecionada, ref _empresaSelecionada, value);
        }

        private Operador _operadorSelecionado;
        public Operador OperadorSelecionado
        {
            get => _operadorSelecionado;
            set => Set(() => OperadorSelecionado, ref _operadorSelecionado, value);
        }

        public void InserirProduto()
        {
            ListaProdutos.Add(new Produto());
            check++;
        }

        public void ExcluirProduto()
        {
            ListaProdutos.Remove(ProdutoSelecionado);
            check++;
        }

        public bool CanExcluirProduto()
        {
            return ProdutoSelecionado != null;
        }

        public void InserirUnidade()
        {
            ListaUnidades.Add(new UnidadeMedida());
            check++;
        }

        public void ExcluirUnidade()
        {
            ListaUnidades.Remove(UnidadeSelecionada);
            check++;
        }

        public bool CanExcluirUnidade()
        {
            return UnidadeSelecionada != null;
        }

        public void InserirEmpresa()
        {
            ListaEmpresas.Add(new Empresa());
            check++;
        }

        public void ExcluirEmpresa()
        {
            ListaEmpresas.Remove(EmpresaSelecionada);
            check++;
        }

        public bool CanExcluirEmpresa()
        {
            return EmpresaSelecionada != null;
        }

        public void InserirOperador()
        {
            ListaOperadores.Add(new Operador());
            check++;
        }

        public void ExcluirOperador()
        {
            ListaOperadores.Remove(OperadorSelecionado);
            check++;
        }

        public bool CanExcluirOperador()
        {
            return OperadorSelecionado != null;
        }

        public void Salvar()
        {
            var listaProdutos = ListaProdutos.ToList();
            var listaUnidades = ListaUnidades.ToList();
            var listaEmpresas = ListaEmpresas.ToList();
            var listaOperadores = ListaOperadores.ToList();

            listaProdutos = listaProdutos.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Descricao)).ToList();
            listaUnidades = listaUnidades.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Descricao)).ToList();
            listaEmpresas = listaEmpresas.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Descricao)).ToList();
            listaOperadores = listaOperadores.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Nome)).ToList();

            ProdutosAccess.SetListProdutos(listaProdutos);
            ProdutosAccess.SetListUnidades(listaUnidades);
            ProdutosAccess.SetListEmpresas(listaEmpresas);
            ProdutosAccess.SetListOperadores(listaOperadores);

            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText: "Dados salvos com sucesso!",
                           caption: "Gerenciar Dados", button: MessageBoxButton.OK,
                           icon: MessageBoxImage.Information);

            Sair();
        }

        public bool CanSalvar()
        {
            if (check == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void Cancelar()
        {
            Sair();
        }

        public void Sair()
        {
            Navigator.CloseWindowByDataContext(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code... my first intuition is that you just need to set your UpdateSourceTrigger on the text field. Might be easier with an MCVE though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BradleDotNET mentioned just set the UpdateSourceTrigger inside your TextBox Text binding to PropertyChanged and it should work.